# What software is photographer Diar Kamal showing on his Facebook page and Instagram feed?

Tags: photo-editing, digital, software-recommendation

Hello every one a few days ago I came by this photographer's photos. He posted some screen shots of a software I want to know the name of the software. Thank You.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [Scratch](http://www.assimilateinc.com/products/scratch), by Assimilate Inc. This is (very pricey) color-grading software used for video, and not normally used for still photography (although it can work with and produce stills).

In fact I think this is just the free [Scratch Play](http://www.postmagazine.com/Publications/Post-Magazine/2014/March-1-2014/Review-Assimilates-Scratch-Play.aspx), which is a video player with the ability to generate color correction tables to use in the full software. I think that because other images like [this one](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1584435238468936&set=pb.100007074247158.-2207520000.1439054574.&type=3&src=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-xpa1%2Ft31.0-8%2F10982593_1584435238468936_1900568228836710493_o.jpg&smallsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-xpt1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-9%2F11008092_1584435238468936_1900568228836710493_n.jpg%3Foh%3Dd916953ba83edcb10172af13ab2f6145%26oe%3D5644FAD9&size=1365%2C752) found on the [photographer's Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Kish.Maliik/photos_stream) have advertising in the corner, which strongly implies that it is the adware player rather than the full software.

I have no idea why one would want to do this — I don't think the player can actually save any color edits for direct use. It's possible that the photographer is making color adjustments in Scratch Play and then saving them by taking screenshots.